# Error Finding Windows Session LDAP username - C#

Tags: c#, ldap, userprincipal

In C# client code, I try to find the username for the Windows session with the following code.  It was working in an LDAP test environment.  In a different LDAP environment it fails with the error:

### Error getting name: The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

```
try
{
    // Set the current user
    UserPrincipal curUser = UserPrincipal.Current;
    String user = curUser.SamAccountName;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    LogWriter.WriteError("Error getting name: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Is this a security problem?  Is there another way to get the LDAP logged in username.

Comment: Is it running under a local Windows account (not a domain account)? Does `curUser.Name` work?